# How do I put this AWK function in a for loop to extract columns?

Tags: shell, for-loop, multidimensional-array, awk

I have tens of files (such as fA.txt, fB.txt and fc.txt) and want an output as shown in fALL.txt.

```
fA.txt:  
id    V   W   X   Y   Z  
a     1   2   4   8   16   
b     3   6   13  17  18  
c     5   1   20  4   8  
   
fB.txt:  
id    F    G   H   J   K  
a     2    5   9   7   12  
b     4    9   12  3   19  
c     6    13  2   40  7  
 
fC.txt:  
id    L    M   N    O  P  
a     7    2   19   8  16  
b     8    6   12  23  47  
c     91   11  15  19  80  

desired output
  
fALL.txt:
  
id    fA_V   fB_F   fC_L    
a     1      2      7    
b     3      4      8    
c     5      6      91    

id    fA_W   fB_G   fC_M  
a     2      5      2  
b     6      9      6  
c     1      13     11  

id    fA_X   fB_H   fC_N  
a     4      9      19  
b     13     12     12  
c     20     2      15  

id    fA_Y  fB_J   fC_O  
a     8      7      8  
b     17     3      23  
c     4      40     19  

id    fA_Z  fB_K   fC_P  
a     16     12     16  
b     18     19     47  
c     8      7      80
```

I have seen the following AWK code on this site that works for input files with only 2 columns.
`'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0; next} {a[FNR] = a[FNR] OFS $2} END{for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i]}' file1 file2 file3`  For my case, I have modified the above as follows and it works for extracting the second columns:
`'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1 OFS $2; next} {a[FNR] = a[FNR] OFS $2} END{for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) print a[i]}' file1 file2 file3`  I have tried putting the above into a for loop to extract the subsequent columns but have not been successful. Any helpful hints will be greatly appreciated.
The first block of data in the desired output is the second column from each of the input files with a header concatenated from the filename and the column header in the respective input file. The subsequent blocks are the third, fourth, fifth columns from each input file.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for sharing your efforts in your question. Could you please do mention the logic of getting the sample shown output too in your question(not in comments) because it's not clear how you are getting expected output, thank you.

Comment: logic added as requested

Comment: This is still unclear. How do we split up the output into smaller pieces? The obvious and natural arrangement would be to have a single matrix where you add more columns if you find new features to extract (or perhaps more naturally an inverted matrix, where you add one row for each new feature, and one new column for each new file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `gnu awk` should work for you.

```sh
cat tab.awk
BEGIN {
   OFS = "\t"
   for (i=1; i<=ARGC; ++i) {
      fn = ARGV[i]
      sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "_", fn)
      fhdr[i] = fn
   }
}
!seen[$1]++ {
   keys[++k] = $1
}
{
   for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i)
      map[$1][i] = map[$1][i] (map[$1][i] == "" ? "" : OFS) (FNR == 1 ? fhdr[ARGIND] : "") $i
}
END {
   for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) {
      for (j=1; j<=k; j++) {
         key = keys[j]
         print key, map[key][i]
      }
      print ""
   }
}
```

Then use it as:

```
awk -f tab.awk f{A,B,C}.txt
```

```sh
id  fA_V  fB_F  fC_L
a   1     2     7
b   3     4     8
c   5     6     91

id  fA_W  fB_G  fC_M
a   2     5     2
b   6     9     6
c   1     13    11

id  fA_X  fB_H  fC_N
a   4     9     19
b   13    12    12
c   20    2     15

id  fA_Y  fB_J  fC_O
a   8     7     8
b   17    3     23
c   4     40    19

id  fA_Z  fB_K  fC_P
a   16    12    16
b   18    19    47
c   8     7     80
```

---

**Explanation:**

```sh
 BEGIN {
   OFS = "\t"                   # Use output field separator as tab
   for (i=1; i<=ARGC; ++i) {    # for each filename in input
      fn = ARGV[i]
      sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "_", fn)  # remove anything after dot with a _
      fhdr[i] = fn              # and save it in fhdr associative array
   }
}
!seen[$1]++ {                   # if this id is not found in seen array
   keys[++k] = $1               # store in seen and in keys array by index
}
{
   for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i)        # for each field starting from 2nd column
      map[$1][i] = map[$1][i] (map[$1][i] == "" ? "" : OFS) (FNR == 1 ? fhdr[ARGIND] : "") $i
   # build 2 dimensional array map where key is $1,i and value is column  value
   # for 1st record prefix column value with part filename stored in fhdr array
   # we keep appending value in this array with OFS delimiter
}
END {                           # do this in the end
   for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) {      # for each column position from 2 onwards
      for (j=1; j<=k; j++) {    # for each id stored in keys array 
         key = keys[j]
         print key, map[key][i] # print id and value text built above
      }
      print ""                  # print a line break
   }
}
```

Comment: I  have added detailed explanation.

Comment: May I assume that the code I posted is not readily for-looped and hence the need to re-write it? I like your code and I'm dissecting it to get a better understanding thereof. Question - If the input files f{A,B,C} had the format below, what needs to change to make the code work? i.e first 3 lines contain file information (to be retained in the desired output file only once), column headers on Line 4)  
Line 1:  Universal Data..           
Line 2: Compilation by     
Line 3: Spectral Dissipation    
 id  fA_V  fB_F  fC_L

Comment: If filenames are just `f{A,B,C}` with their `.txt` extensions then use `fhdr[i] = ARGV[i] "_"` inside first for loop `for (i=1; i<=ARGC; ++i)` and get rid of 3 lines inside.